# Powershell exclude issue with version 4

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to copy a folder recursively and exclude some files while coping

On my local machine *(with windows 10 OS)* i have power-shell version

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  251
```

The command below copies `c:\source\publish` folder to `c:\dest` and excludes the files as expected

```
$exclude = @('appsettings.staging.json','appsettings.production.json')

Copy-Item -Path "c:\source\publish" -Destination "c:\dest" -Exclude $exclude -recurse -Force -PassThru
```

On our build server i have the following powershell version

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

When i run the above command on the build server, it  copies the folder to `c:\dest` as expected but DOES NOT exclude the files.

On the build server, to exclude the files i have to append `\*` to source path something like below

```
Copy-Item -Path "c:\source\publish\*" -Destination "c:\dest" -Exclude $exclude -recurse -Force -PassThru
```

The command above excludes the files, however it does not create `publish` folder under `c:\dest` instead it copies files directly to `c:\dest`

How do i copy the folder but also exclude the files with version 4.0.-1.-1

Comment: I know `Get-ChildItem` has issues with the `-Exclude` parameter as well.  I'd suggest filtering through that before passing to `Copy-Item` unless you're using the `-Container` switch.

Answer (score 1):

If you define different paths you are going to get different results. Specifying `c:\source\publish` says to get that folder `c:\source\publish\*` says to get everything *within* that folder, excluding the folder itself. So your destination path would need to account for that. You can simply create the path first, and then copy to it.

```
$exclude = @('appsettings.staging.json','appsettings.production.json')
$Dest = New-Item -Path "c:\dest\publish"-ItemType Directory -Force
Copy-Item -Path "c:\source\publish\*" -Destination $Dest.FullName -Exclude $exclude -recurse -Force -PassThru
```

Comment: thats what i was thinking, but what if the source folder name changes in future, then i have to update destination

Comment: If you are concerned with the source changing you can build logic in to determine the destination based off your source. gms0ulman already included that in his answer, so I'll just refer you to that.

Answer (score 1):

You could build logic based on the version of PowerShell being used.

```
$exclude = @('appsettings.staging.json','appsettings.production.json')
$source  = "c:\source\publish"
$dest    = "c:\dest"


if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 4){
    $dest    = $dest + "\" + (Split-Path $source -leaf)
    $source  = $source + '\*'
    New-Item -Path $dest -ItemType Directory -Force
}

Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $dest -Exclude $exclude -recurse -Force -PassThru
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method, more interressant because you can modify the where condition to be more specific :

```
$exclude = @('appsettings.staging.json','appsettings.production.json')
$Dest = New-Item -Path "c:\dest"-ItemType Directory -Force

Get-ChildItem "c:\source\publish" -file -Recurse | where name -notin $exclude | Copy-Item -Destination $Dest.FullName -Force
```